# Root / nested object query

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to query a root / nested object combination so that when root part 
matches (Q1) and the nested object matches (Q2) the document is returned with 
the matching nested object, and when Q1 matches AND Q2 doesn't the the root object is returned. 
I tried (and assuming Q1 matches):

```
  "bool":  
     "must":[  // Q1 ]
     "should":[ // Q2  ]
```

returns all nested objects regardless of Q2.

```
  "bool":  
     "must":[ // Q1 ]
     "must":[ // Q2 ]
```

returns zero matches if Q2 dosent match